# write to multi-dimensional list in python gives unexpected results

Tags: python

I want to create a pre-sized multi-dimensional list.  I have as an experiment:

```
>>>md = [[0]*5]*5
>>>md[1][1] = 6
>>>md
[[0, 6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0, 0]]
```

which I don't expect.

then:

```
>>> a = [[0] * 5 for i in range(5)]
>>> a[1][1] = 6
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

which is what I expect.  what is going on here?